# Blender 2.8 Error Message: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'modifiers' when changing `Decimate` values

Tags: python

When changing the `Decimate` values in Blender, I get the following error:

```
import bpy
class ReducePolygons(bpy.types.Operator):
   
    bl_idname = "reduce.polygons"
    bl_label = "Reduce Polygons of your Mesh"


    def execute(self, context):
        bpy.ops.object.modifier_add(type='DECIMATE')
        bpy.context.object.modifiers["Decimate"].decimate_type = 'UNSUBDIV'
        bpy.context.object.modifiers["Decimate"].iterations = 1
        bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply(apply_as='DATA', modifier="Decimate")
        return {'FINISHED'}

class LayoutDemoPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    """Creates a Panel in the scene context of the properties editor"""
    bl_label = "Layout Demo"
    bl_idname = "SCENE_PT_layout"
    bl_space_type = 'PROPERTIES'
    bl_region_type = 'WINDOW'
    bl_context = "scene"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout

        layout.label(text="Mesh Optimizations:")
        row = layout.row()
        row.scale_y = 2.0
        row.operator("reduce.polygons")


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(ReducePolygons)
    bpy.utils.register_class(LayoutDemoPanel)
    


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(ReducePolygons)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(LayoutDemoPanel)
    


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

> Error Message:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'modifiers'
location: <unknown location>:-1
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when trying to apply a different modifier using a similar method.  I don't understand why the modifier did not just use the active object, but it works if you use a variable that refers to the object to define the modifier options.  Here is a ClassPolygons that should work:

class ReducePolygons(bpy.types.Operator):

```
bl_idname = "reduce.polygons"
bl_label = "Reduce Polygons of your Mesh"

def execute(self, context):
    bpy.ops.object.modifier_add(type='DECIMATE')
    obj=bpy.context.active_object
    obj.modifiers["Decimate"].decimate_type = 'UNSUBDIV'
    obj.modifiers["Decimate"].iterations = 1
    bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply (modifier="Decimate")
    return {'FINISHED'}
```

I don't know if the apply_as='DATA' part is necessary.  According to the  documentation, Blender 2.9 only has a type option in bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply, but when I tried to use it, I got a 'keyword "type" unrecognized' error'.